# Why can't I a add reaction to a message in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm making a drop Discord bot but when I send a message how would I store it and add a reaction?

I was previously using `discord.ext.commands` but now I have switched to using `discord.app_commands`. This was the code I was using previously:

```py
msg = await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed)
await msg.message.add_reaction('')
```

The error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/discord/app_commands/tree.py",
line 1248, in _call
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)   File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py",
line 853, in _invoke_with_namespace
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py",
line 846, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'drop' raised
an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute
'message'
```

For some reason the `msg` variable is `None` how can I fix this?
This only happend after I began using  `discord.app_commands`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.